# Azure App Service - 403 Forbidden Error During API POST Request with OSWAP_3.2 WAF Policy Enabled"

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I'm encountering an issue with my Azure-hosted application. It's hosted on Azure app service, and I have the OSWAP_3.2 WAF policy enabled on my application gateway.

Recently, I've started receiving a 403 Forbidden error when making an API POST request. I'm using Postman for this request, and I believe the "Content-Length" header is automatically added by Postman.

Here are the details of the error from the firewall logs:

```
{
    "timeStamp": "2023-08-15T05:25:12+00:00",
    "resourceId": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/XXXXX-XXXX-XX-AA76-391CEB2CFDBA/RESOURCEGROUPS/OSS-XXX-USE2-XXXXXSVC-DEV-RG01/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.NETWORK/APPLICATIONGATEWAYS/AZUSWAXXXXX",
    "operationName": "ApplicationGatewayFirewall",
    "category": "ApplicationGatewayFirewallLog",
    "properties": {
        "instanceId": "appgw_0",
        "clientIp": "20.187.22.22",
        "requestUri": "\/connect\/token",
        "ruleSetType": "OWASP CRS",
        "ruleSetVersion": "3.2",
        "ruleId": "920160",
        "ruleGroup": "REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT",
        "message": "Content-Length HTTP header is not numeric.",
        "action": "Matched",
        "details": {
            "message": "Pattern match ^\\d+$ at REQUEST_HEADERS:content-length.",
            "data": "{ found within [REQUEST_HEADERS:]}",
            "file": "REQUEST-920-PROTOCOL-ENFORCEMENT.conf",
            "line": "130"
        },
        "hostname": "dev.xyz.com",
        "transactionId": "23e63bed8a6e218e2d286ca237216051",
        "policyId": "154#_subscriptions_xxxxx-xxx-xxx-aa76-391ceb2cfdba_resourceGroups_OSS-XXX-USE2-XXXX-DEV-RG01_providers_Microsoft.Network_ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies_WAF-azuswa1xxxxxx",
        "policyScope": "Global",
        "policyScopeName": "Global",
        "engine": "Azwaf"
    }
}
```

I tried adding an exclusion to stop checking the "Content-Length" header, but that didn't work. Could this be a false positive?

Any advice or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.